# sort by aggregration script to get top 100 element in Elastic Search

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch

I am working on elastic search

There are several fields of the object for example a, b ,c

I can use that a, b,c to calculate a Score

I will need to get top 100 element base on the Score

The thing is I cannot update or create a new field in the database

My original idea is to pull all of them back then calculate and then sort for the top 100

However, it's not possible since my local host is not fast enough

Is there any way i can write an aggregrate line to do it on the elastic server then get the top 100 element back

Answer (score 1):

I am quite new to elasticsearch but i will try taking short at the problem. In the older version of elasticsearch you could achieve this by using "facets" but in the current version this can be achieved by "aggs" or aggregation and "terms" in it.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html